# Frame hides under main frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm having Menubar that contains `JMenu` and `JMenuItems`

```
class MenuBar implements MenuListener, ActionListener {
    private JMenu menuA;
    private JMenu menuB;
    private JMenuItem subMenuA;
    private JMenuItem subMenuB;

    public MenuBar() {
        menuB.addMenuListener(this);
        subMenuA.addActionListener(this);
        subMenuB.addActionListener(this);
        //add submenus to menuA, etc
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if(source == subMenuA) {
            new MyFrame("One")
        }
        if(source == subMenuB) {
            new MyFrame("Two")
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if(source == replaceMenu) {
            new MyFrame("Three")
        }
    }
}
```

Now, once I click `subMenuA` or `subMenuB` - it correctly opens new frame. Click on `menuB` should have same funcionality. I realized I can't simply `addActionListener(this)` to `JMenu` so instead I'm adding `addMenuListener(this)`. The point is, it works a bit different than `ActionListener`. Both frames I'm opening have the same implementation. But if I use `ActionListener` - frame opens and stays open, on the other hand, if I'm using `MenuListener` - it opens and then hides under main frame.

Here is code of those frames

```
MyFrame(String title) {
    frame = new JFrame(title);
    initComponents(frame);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    frame.setLocation(((Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width  - frame.getSize().width) / 2),
                ((Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height - frame.getSize().height) / 2));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

How to avoid `Frame` created via `MenuListener::menuSelected` from hiding under main frame?

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) `frame.setLocation(null);` will center a frame on screen. 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Oops! Trying (2) again.. 2) `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` ..

Comment: *How to avoid Frame created via MenuListener::menuSelected from hiding under main frame?* - don't use a JFrame. For the child windox you should use a JDialog and specify the frame as the parent.